# Getting Exception org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext

Tags: java, exception, log4j

My code is very simple using apache-log4j-2.0.2:

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jtest {
  static Logger log =Logger.getLogger(Log4jtest.class);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
        log.debug("This is debug message");
  }

}
```

But I'm getting exception like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be          cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext``
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:41)
at Log4jtest.<clinit>(Log4jtest.java:11)
```

Why is the exception coming from a simple program?

Comment: please check your log4j cconfiguration file.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I think I was telling SLF4J to log with a certain binding and then telling log4j to send logging message to SLF4J, which wasn't properly configured, due to the .jars that were included in the classpath.

In my case I had a jar like this, that when remove, resolved the issue (by letting log4j log using it's own framework, instead of trying to use the SLFJ framework)

log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.2.jar

Answer (score 87):

> Remove below jar's from class path and it should fix the issue -

```
log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.2.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.2-sources.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2-sources.jar
```

> I was able to replicate and fix the issue after downloading
>   apache-log4j-2.0.2 from
>       http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/2.0.2/apache-log4j-2.0.2-bin.zip.

Comment: Also, please do remember to accept your answers (all of them) if they have given you satisfactory answers (by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answers), it would be helpful to the community

Comment: This works as cool but may I know the exact reason how its happened

Comment: This worked for me too. I excluded the sources and tests jar supplied within the official Log4J Package.  Then added the flume-ng-sdk jar to remove ClassNotFoundException. Then finally removed these 2 JARs for this ClassCastException. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: This solution is not good if you *want* log4j to forward log events to slf4j via `log4j-to-slf4j`.

Comment: not a good answer but degrading log4j2 version from 2.11.x to 2.8.x worked for me.

Comment: I don't have these jars but still get error.

Comment: @PhilipRego same here did u manage to resolve this?

Comment: @Mee I don't remember

Answer (score 14):

I was using Maven. I found that declaring my `log4j`/`slf4j` dependencies at the top of the `<dependencies>` list (before Spring Boot, which used `logback`) fixed the issue.

---

To @TheCodingFrog's credit, adding exclusions to my Spring Boot dependencies also solved the problem. Like so:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

**NOTE: If you care about which logging framework is actually used**, one perhaps important difference is that with @TheCodingFrog's method, `slf4j` retained `logback` as the binding:

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

whereas, with the method I used, `slf4j`/`log4j` was used:

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

---

In case anyone's interested, the `log4j`/`slf4j` dependencies I used are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, `log4j-core` and `log4j-to-slf4j` shouldn't be used together. Derived `LoggerContext` cannot cast for log4j-core. If you want to use log4j to slf4j adapter, you should remove `log4j-core` and add just `log4j-api` and `log4j-to-slf4j`.

---

I encountered a similar problem in Elasticsearch and Spring Boot. Elasticsearch 6.8.2 uses log4j 2.7.11. When I exclude log4j-core dependency I face a problem like that:

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Configurator*

I found a solution for mocking log4j-core: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19415#issuecomment-301057712