# Log4j2 Annotation getting errors from Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, log4j2

When using Log4j2 in Intellij for a groovy/gradle project, log shows up red as if the injection is not working. Gradle runs and builds but every file in IntelliJ shows errors which is annoying.

dependencies

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5'
```

Source

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j2
@Log4j2
class TestLog4j2 {
    public static void log(String message) {
        log.error(message)
```

log from log.error is displayed in red and displays error, cannot resolve symbol 'log'
The log4j2.xml file is in the classpath and works.
@Log4j and even @Slf4j both work
Using IntelliJ 15.03 Build IU-143.1821
Project is using Groovy 2.4.4 and Gradle 2.3

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Is you IntelliJ project structure built by using the Gradle plugin, where it creates the classpath from the dependencies?

Comment: Might have to enable annotation processing within intellij.

Comment: Look close answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866765/building-with-lomboks-slf4j-and-intellij-cannot-find-symbol-log

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when using groovy's `@Log4j2` annotation.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25894425/2089675) was to exclude the following module in gradle:

```
configurations.all {
  exclude module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
}
```